# Помогите переместить в другое место код!

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть страница с товаром:

```html
<?php 
   define('myeshop', true);
   include("include/db_connect.php");
   include("functions/functions.php");
   session_start();
   include("include/auth_cookie.php");
  
   $id = clear_string($_GET["id"]); 

     $seoquery = mysql_query("SELECT seo_words,seo_description FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id' AND visible='1'",$link);
     
     If (mysql_num_rows($seoquery) > 0)
     {
        $resquery = mysql_fetch_array($seoquery);
     }   
   
  If ($id != $_SESSION['countid'])
{
$querycount = mysql_query("SELECT count FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id'",$link);
$resultcount = mysql_fetch_array($querycount); 

$newcount = $resultcount["count"] + 1;

$update = mysql_query ("UPDATE table_products SET count='$newcount' WHERE products_id='$id'",$link);  
}

$_SESSION['countid'] = $id; 
      
?>

<div class="page-container" id="PageContainer">
<main class="main-content" id="MainContent" role="main">
<?php
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id' AND visible='1'",$link);
If (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0)
{
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
do
{   
if  (strlen($row1["image"]) > 0 && file_exists("./uploads_images/".$row1["image"]))
{
$img_path = './uploads_images/'.$row1["image"];
$max_width = 300; 
$max_height = 300; 
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path); 
$ratioh = $max_height/$height; 
$ratiow = $max_width/$width; 
$ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow); 

$width = intval($ratio*$width); 
$height = intval($ratio*$height);    
}else
{
$img_path = "/images/no-image.png";
$width = 110;
$height = 200;
}     

// Количество отзывов 
$query_reviews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_reviews WHERE products_id = '$id' AND moderat='1'",$link);  
$count_reviews = mysql_num_rows($query_reviews);


echo  '



<div id="shopify-section-product-template" class="shopify-section"><div class="product-template__container page-width" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="ProductSection-product-template" data-section-id="product-template" data-section-type="product" data-enable-history-state="true">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="OSS Charloween Tee Black">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="https://onsomeshit.com/products/oss-charloween-tee-black">
  <meta itemprop="image" content="//styleshop.net.ua/images/future_tee_195x195@2x.jpg?v=1509391637">

  


  <div class="grid product-single">
    <div class="grid__item product-single__photos medium-up--one-half"><div id="FeaturedImageZoom-product-template" class="product-single__photo product-single__photo--has-thumbnails" data-zoom="//styleshop.net.ua/images/future_tee_195x195@2x.jpg?v=1509391637">
        <img src="//styleshop.net.ua/images/future_tee_195x195@2x.jpg?v=1509391637" alt="OSS Charloween Tee Black" id="FeaturedImage-product-template" class="product-featured-img js-zoom-enabled">
      </div>

      
        

        <div class="thumbnails-wrapper">
          
          <ul class="grid grid--uniform product-single__thumbnails product-single__thumbnails-product-template">
            
              <li class="grid__item medium-up--one-quarter product-single__thumbnails-item">
Здесь место для картинок!
              </li>
           
            
          </ul>
          
        </div>
      
    </div>

    <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
      <div class="product-single__meta">

        <h1 itemprop="name" class="product-single__title">'.$row1["title"].'</h1>

        

        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
          <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">

          <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">

          <p class="product-single__price product-single__price-product-template">
            
              <span class="visually-hidden">Regular price</span>
              <s id="ComparePrice-product-template" class="hide"></s>
              <span class="product-price__price product-price__price-product-template">
                <span id="ProductPrice-product-template"
                  itemprop="price" content="30.0">
                  '.group_numerals($row1["price"]).' грн
                </span>
                <span class="product-price__sale-label product-price__sale-label-product-template hide">Sale</span>
              </span>
            
          </p>

          <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="product-form product-form-product-template" data-section="product-template">
            
              
                <div class="selector-wrapper js product-form__item">
                  <label for="SingleOptionSelector-0">
                    Размер
                  </label>
                  <select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-template product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-0" data-index="option1">
                    
    '.$row1["size_s"].'
 '.$row1["size_m"].'
 '.$row1["size_l"].'
 '.$row1["size_xl"].'
 '.$row1["size_36"].'
 '.$row1["size_37"].'
 '.$row1["size_38"].'
 '.$row1["size_39"].'
 '.$row1["size_40"].'
 '.$row1["size_41"].'
 '.$row1["size_42"].'
 '.$row1["size_43"].'
 '.$row1["size_44"].'
 '.$row1["size_45"].'
                    
                  </select>
                </div>
              
            </select>

            
              



          </form>
    <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn--small-wide" id="add-cart-view" value="В корзину"  data-id="'.$row1["products_id"].'" > 

        </div>

        <div class="product-single__description rte" itemprop="description">
          Описание товара
        </div></div></div>

';

   
}
 while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1));


 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploads_images WHERE products_id='$id'",$link);
If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo '<div id="block-img-slide">
      <ul>';
do
{
    
$img_path = './uploads_images/'.$row["image"];
$max_width = 70; 
$max_height = 70; 
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path); 
$ratioh = $max_height/$height; 
$ratiow = $max_width/$width; 
$ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow); 

$width = intval($ratio*$width); 
$height = intval($ratio*$height);    
    
    
echo '
<div id="block-img-slide">
      <ul>
<li>
<a class="image-modal" href="#image'.$row["id"].'"><img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a>
</li>
</div>
</ul>
';
}
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
 echo '
   
        ';
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id' AND visible='1'",$link);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo '
';

$query_reviews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_reviews WHERE products_id='$id' AND moderat='1' ORDER BY reviews_id DESC",$link);

If (mysql_num_rows($query_reviews) > 0)
{
$row_reviews = mysql_fetch_array($query_reviews);
do
{

echo '


';
        
}
 while ($row_reviews = mysql_fetch_array($query_reviews));
}
else
{
    echo '';
} 



echo '


';

}
 
?>
</div>
```

В самом низу есть код:

```html
';

   
}
 while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1));


 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploads_images WHERE products_id='$id'",$link);
If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo '<div id="block-img-slide">
      <ul>';
do
{
    
$img_path = './uploads_images/'.$row["image"];
$max_width = 70; 
$max_height = 70; 
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path); 
$ratioh = $max_height/$height; 
$ratiow = $max_width/$width; 
$ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow); 

$width = intval($ratio*$width); 
$height = intval($ratio*$height);    
    
    
echo '
<div id="block-img-slide">
      <ul>
<li>
<a class="image-modal" href="#image'.$row["id"].'"><img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /></a>
</li>
</div>
</ul>
';
}
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
 echo '
   
        ';
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id' AND visible='1'",$link);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo '
';

$query_reviews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_reviews WHERE products_id='$id' AND moderat='1' ORDER BY reviews_id DESC",$link);

If (mysql_num_rows($query_reviews) > 0)
{
$row_reviews = mysql_fetch_array($query_reviews);
do
{

echo '


';
        
}
 while ($row_reviews = mysql_fetch_array($query_reviews));
}
else
{
    echo '';
} 



echo '


';

}
```

Мне необходимо чтобы этот кусок кода был там где написано "**Здесь место для картинок!**". Пытался тупо скопировать и вставить вверх но тогда ничего не работает. Или как же снизу функции поместить в самый вверх к остальным.

Answer (score 0):

Так как используется echo. Где `Здесь место для картинок!` нужно вставить следующее:

```
'.
//ваш php код
.'
```

Comment: сделал но теперь вообще ничего на странице не отображается: http://185.185.69.207/view_content.php?id=6, сам код вот сюда поместил чтобы просмотрели правильно сделал или нет: http://185.185.69.207/1.txt